# Surveymonkey: call webhook when survey is completed

Tags: surveymonkey

I would like to receive webhook calls to my own service when a survey has been completed.  I do not want to poll surveymonkey for results. I noticed there is some obscure documentation here: http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/WebHook-PUT but it is not useful.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: That page you link to is for Wufoo.  The only real option you have here that I know of is to have a custom redirect at the end of your survey that takes you to a page of your choice at the end of a survey.  You need a platinum plan for this though ($780 / year) - https://www.surveymonkey.com/pricing/details/

Comment: Actually another thing you can check out is Zapier's integration with SurveyMonkey, I think they potentially handle the polling for you https://zapier.com/zapbook/surveymonkey/

Comment: thanks @MilesCederman-Haysom however, the link I refer to is on surveymonkey -- which is the exact same as on wufoo site. Clearly I could switch to wufoo as it does exactly what I want (I've even tested it).

I don't want to pay for Zapier - on top of SurveyMonkey. I just want surveymonkey to call my web-hook (like wufoo does) after  a survey is completed.

its a shame SurveyMonkey doesn't do that.

Comment: It's on the SurveyMonkey site but it's just the help page for the Wufoo API. We're definitely aware that callbacks would be a great feature to have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can setup a webhook with [SurveyMonkey API v3](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#webhooks). To create a webhook, you would make a request like:

```
POST /v3/webhooks
{
  "name": "My Survey Completed Webhook",
  "event_type": "response_completed",
  "object_type": "survey",
  "object_ids": ["<survey_id1>", "<survey_id2>" ...],
  "subscription_url": "https://example.com/surveys_responses",
}
```

Now every time a survey is completed, a notification will be made to the `subscription_url` specified when creating the webhook. The notification will be a skinny payload with the `response_id` which you can use to [fetch responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses-id):

```
GET /v3/surveys/{id}/responses/{id}
```

Comment: Any idea how to listen for all responses in case we don't know all `object_ids` ahead of time? (Otherwise, it seems I'm left with this cumbersome strategy: set up a 'new survey' webhook which in turn sets up a 'response_completed' webhook with the now-known survey_id)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't currently support getting a webhook for "any" survey.